# Где хранить доп.информацию о окнах WINAPI?

Tags: c, winapi

Lang:C
я делаю текстовый редактор(очень простенький)
И у меня есть функция сохранения.
То-есть вы открываете файл, потом написали что-то захотели сохранить, нажимаете кнопку "сохранить"
И вылезает окно "куда сохранить"
Мне нужно чтобы сохранение происходило без окна в котором выбираешь путь до этого файла чтобы его же и сохранить
Мне нужно чтобы после открытия файла, путь записывался куда либо, чтобы потом при сохранении ты не выбирал куда зачем почему
Я мог бы сделать переменную простую и в ней держать этот путь, но подумал что вдруг есть специальная функция, для того чтобы там хранить такие данные ?
Например, я делаю редактор, с несколькими окнами редактирования разных файлов, и вот чтобы я обращался к определенному окну и из него брал данные (путь) для сохранения

Comment: Сохраняйте ее в пользовательском объекте, ассоциированном с этим окном. Указатель на него можно сохранить посредством `GetWindowLongPtrW` `SetWindowLongPtrW`.

Comment: @Fobars, а зачем усложнять ? Чем к примеру не устраивает та переменная о которой Вы писали ? То есть, как смысл использовать некую специальную функцию, которая все равно у себя внутри создать условную переменную, в которой и будет хранить имя этого пути.